# Ember.js: How to resolve an async hasMany relationship within Ember.Route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do i resolve an async hasMany relationship within Ember.Route?

To be specific: I can't figure out why `this.modelFor('collection').get('id')` returns an ID but `this.modelFor('collection').get('recipes_refs')` an object (maybe a promise?).

I have to resolve `recipes_refs` because i need to figure out if the currently viewed recipe collection contains the currently requested recipe.

```
// Route
App.CollectionRecipeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        console.log(this.modelFor('collection').get('id'))
    }
});

// Models
App.Collection = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    assets: DS.attr(),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    recipes_refs: DS.hasMany('recipe', { async: true })
});

App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    ingredients: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `this.modelFor('collection').get('recipes_refs')` is returning a promise.  You can deal with it just like any other promise by using `then` to handle the cases where it resolves or rejects.

```
this.modelFor('collection').get('recipes_refs').then(function(recipes){
  // At this point 'recipes' is a collection of live objects
  recipes.forEach(function(recipe,i){
    // do something with each recipe in the collection
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `recipes` (in your case `i`) here is not an array?

Comment: `recipes` is an Enumerable, which is very similar to an array.  You can read about it here : http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/  In the `function` passed to `forEach` I had the arguments labeled backwards.  I've fixed that now.